# Accessing JQ Variables Using Arguments

Tags: linux, bash, shell, jq

I am trying to get values base on key of this JSON:

```
{
  "streams": {
    "vs-first": {
      "version": "2.33.0",
      "branch": "ewewew",
      "hash": "ewewewewe",
      "widgets": []
    },
    "vs-second": {
      "version": "1.58.0",
      "branch": "ewewew",
      "hash": "ewewew",
      "widgets": []
    },
    "vs-third": {
      "version": "1.42.0",
      "branch": "ewewew",
      "hash": "ewewe",
      "widgets": []
    },
    "vs-fourth": {
      "version": "1.58.0",
      "branch": "eewfwfef",
      "hash": "vvfffsfsf",
      "widgets": []
    },
    "vs-fifth": {
      "version": "1.39.0",
      "branch": "fvrvvsdvds",
      "hash": "vvsvdsvds",
      "widgets": [
        "1",
        "2",
        "3",
        "4"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This is my Script implementation:

```
jq -r '.streams|keys[]' $vsconfig | while read key ; do
    if [ $key == "[" ] || [ $key == "]" ]; then
      continue
    fi

    if [ $key == "vs-first" ]; then
      version=$(jq -r '.streams.vs-first.version' $vsconfig)
      branch=$(jq -r '.streams.vs-first.branch' $vsconfig)
      hash=$(jq -r '.streams.vs-first.hash' $vsconfig)

      filename="one_file-$version-$branch-$hash.zip"
      createdUrl="$someurl/$version/$filename"

      curl $createdUrl --output ./som/random/dir --create-dirs
      ...
    else
      version=$(jq -r --arg v keyvar $key 'streams.[$keyvar].branch' $vsconfig)
      branch=`jq --arg keyvar "streams.$key.branch" '$keyvar' $vsconfig`
      hash=`jq --arg keyvar "streams.$key.hash" '$keyvar' $vsconfig`

      filename = "$key-$version"
      if [ $branch == "some_branch" ]; then
        filename="one_file-$version-$branch-$hash.zip"
      else
        filename="$filename.zip"
      fi

      curl $createdUrl --output ./som/random/dir --create-dirs
    fi

    echo "Version: $version Branch: $branch Hash: $hash"
done
```

I've tried multiple formats, i.e:

```
version=$(jq -r --arg v keyvar $key 'streams.[$keyvar].branch' $vsconfig)
```

And:

```
branch=`jq --arg keyvar "streams.$key.branch" '$keyvar' $vsconfig`
```

It gives this error:

```
jq: error: support/0 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:
```

Comment: I am trying to loop through the `streams.<name>`, get the version, branch and hash and use it to build a url to make a network request. I am new to `jq` if there's a way to do that in a single `jq` invocation, please help with it. Thanks @JohnKugelman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jq is quite sophisticated. The best bet is probably to do all of this inside a single jq invocation and have minimal or no bash scripting.

#### Values only

To start with, you can get each version/branch/hash object by applying `[]` to the `.streams` object. Using `[]` on an object—or key/value map—extracts the values and throws away the keys.

```
$ jq -c '.streams[]' vs.json
{"version":"2.33.0","branch":"ewewew","hash":"ewewewewe","widgets":[]}
{"version":"1.58.0","branch":"ewewew","hash":"ewewew","widgets":[]}
{"version":"1.42.0","branch":"ewewew","hash":"ewewe","widgets":[]}
{"version":"1.58.0","branch":"eewfwfef","hash":"vvfffsfsf","widgets":[]}
{"version":"1.39.0","branch":"fvrvvsdvds","hash":"vvsvdsvds","widgets":[]}
```

Then you can get the individual fields you're interested in by piping the above objects to a filter which grabs `.version`, `.branch`, and `.hash` and throws the three values into an array:

```
$ jq -c '.streams[] | [.version, .branch, .hash]' vs.json
["2.33.0","ewewew","ewewewewe"]
["1.58.0","ewewew","ewewew"]
["1.42.0","ewewew","ewewe"]
["1.58.0","eewfwfef","vvfffsfsf"]
["1.39.0","fvrvvsdvds","vvsvdsvds"]
```

To get it to format the results you can generate strings instead of lists and use `\(...)` to embed values. The `-r` flag tells it to print raw results: print the strings without quotes, in other words.

```
$ jq -r '.streams[] | "Version: \(.version) Branch: \(.branch) Hash: \(.hash)"' vs.json
Version: 2.33.0 Branch: ewewew Hash: ewewewewe
Version: 1.58.0 Branch: ewewew Hash: ewewew
Version: 1.42.0 Branch: ewewew Hash: ewewe
Version: 1.58.0 Branch: eewfwfef Hash: vvfffsfsf
Version: 1.39.0 Branch: fvrvvsdvds Hash: vvsvdsvds
```

#### Keys and values

To add the keys into the mix you can use `to_entries`, which extracts the key/value pairs from an object:

```
$ jq -c '.streams | to_entries[]' vs.json
{"key":"vs-first","value":{"version":"2.33.0","branch":"ewewew","hash":"ewewewewe","widgets":[]}}
{"key":"vs-second","value":{"version":"1.58.0","branch":"ewewew","hash":"ewewew","widgets":[]}}
{"key":"vs-third","value":{"version":"1.42.0","branch":"ewewew","hash":"ewewe","widgets":[]}}
{"key":"vs-fourth","value":{"version":"1.58.0","branch":"eewfwfef","hash":"vvfffsfsf","widgets":[]}}
{"key":"vs-fifth","value":{"version":"1.39.0","branch":"fvrvvsdvds","hash":"vvsvdsvds","widgets":[]}}
```

Pulling out the different fields then becomes:

```
$ jq -c '.streams | to_entries[] | [.key, .value.version, .value.branch, .value.hash]' vs.json
["vs-first","2.33.0","ewewew","ewewewewe"]
["vs-second","1.58.0","ewewew","ewewew"]
["vs-third","1.42.0","ewewew","ewewe"]
["vs-fourth","1.58.0","eewfwfef","vvfffsfsf"]
["vs-fifth","1.39.0","fvrvvsdvds","vvsvdsvds"]
```

Or equivalently, with the repeated `.value` lookups refactored out:

```
jq -c '.streams | to_entries[] | [.key, (.value | .version, .branch, .hash)]' vs.json
["vs-first","2.33.0","ewewew","ewewewewe"]
["vs-second","1.58.0","ewewew","ewewew"]
["vs-third","1.42.0","ewewew","ewewe"]
["vs-fourth","1.58.0","eewfwfef","vvfffsfsf"]
["vs-fifth","1.39.0","fvrvvsdvds","vvsvdsvds"]
```

#### Add bash processing

jq can't do everything, so if you do want to get the results out to bash to do additional processing—e.g., call curl—you could use `-r` to print each value on a separate line and use `read` to read the lines into variables. It would look something like this:

```
jq -r '.streams | to_entries[] | .key, (.value | .version, .branch, .hash)' vs.json |
    while read -r key &&
          read -r version &&
          read -r branch &&
          read -r hash
    do
        ...
    done
```

Comment: I need access to the keys to the dictionary as well. Is there a way I can add it to the second example? i.e: `jq -c '.streams[] | [.key, .version, .branch, .hash]' vs.json` Also, I've modified my question for more clarity, and why I need to split it. I need access to the key, and getting the data. One of the keys has a static implementation, and the others are the same

Comment: Also, the second implementation is just an array with one value

Comment: Okay. This make sense to use, `jq -c '.streams | to_entries[] | [.key, .value.version, .value.branch, .value.hash]' vs.json` but, each record has only one element. i.e: If I do `$item0{0}` it'll give me `["vs-first","2.33.0","ewewew","ewewewewe"]` and not `vs-first`

Comment: Just one more question  if the `widgets` key has values in it, the last item is the only thing that's read. i.e: In the sample JSON above, only 4 is read when I use the bash processing. I tried using read -a widgets to read it as well, and read -r does the same.